# Mixed content in Chrome

Tags: magento-1.9, security, ssl, https

We have a site which is accessed entirely over HTTPS, but sometimes display external content which is HTTP. Anybody can help me why sometimes display external content is HTTP.

Comment: maybe you call some library or an external url that is not secure, f12 in your navigator and check all urls in network tab

Comment: this is the website https://apexwaterfilters.com/ and tell me how to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these images by making them secure and your problem will be solved.

**The list of images:**

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/phone-icon.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/pin_1.png

All the images that you call in http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/coolslider/

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/fast-shipping.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/american-flag.png

All the images that you call in http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/hpimages/

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/kdf.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/arbon.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/sys.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/axeon.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/hydronix.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/resintechinc.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/matterhorn.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/dow.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/free-shipping.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/knowledge-base.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/filter-service.png

http://www.apexwaterfilters.com/media/wysiwyg/water-quality.png

**How to make them secure ?**

In `System > Configuration > Web > Secure`, make sure that the following are set:

> - Base Link URL - `{{secure_base_url}}`
> - Base Skin URL - `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`
> - Base Media URL - `{{secure_base_url}}media/`
> - Base Javascript URL - `{{secure_base_url}}js/`

This way all the paths generated will follow the protocol given in "Base URL". If a page is secure everything on it will also be served secure.

Then You have two ways to update the links when you call the images:

1) `$this->getSkinUrl('images/image_name.png', array('_secure' => true));`

2) `{{config path="web/secure/base_media_url"}}wysiwyg/name_image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You can check what's the reason of that issue in the **Chrome Developer Tool** called Security Overview:

[image]